# why does dataset not preserve its associations in Module[]?

Tags: dataset, scoping

Hello I am perplexed as to why a dataset, ds1 in this example, does not return the association with index and content in it.

```
fnMakeData[] := 
 Module[{ds1}, 
  ds1 = Dataset[
     Thread[{ Table[n, {n, 10}], 
       Table["text" <>  ToString[n], {n, 10}]} ]] &; 
  ds1 = ds1[All, 
    Association["index" -> #[[1]], "content" -> #[[2]] ] &]]
```

A call to fnMakeData[] returns with a dataset without the headers in it.

Does anyone know why this is the case?

Comment: What is the expected behavior here?  I get the same results even if I remove the `fnMakeData[] := 
 Module[{ds1},` part.

Comment: See `AssociationThread`.  As in `AssociationThread[{"index", "content"}, #] & /@ 
  Table[{n, "text" <> ToString[n]}, {n, 10}] // Dataset`

Comment: Remove the `&` from the first assignment to `ds1`.

Comment: Hello @JasonB. the expected behaviour was a Dataset with in the form of list-of-assocations, ie, its headers, like this: {<|"index" -> 1, "content" -> "text1"|>, <|"index" -> 2, 
  "content" -> "text2"|>, <|"index" -> 3, 
  "content" -> "text3"|>, <|"index" -> 4, 
  "content" -> "text4"|>, <|"index" -> 5, 
  "content" -> "text5"|>, <|"index" -> 6, 
  "content" -> "text6"|>, <|"index" -> 7, 
  "content" -> "text7"|>, <|"index" -> 8, 
  "content" -> "text8"|>, <|"index" -> 9, 
  "content" -> "text9"|>, <|"index" -> 10, "content" -> "text10"|>}

Comment: thanks a lot @RohitNamjoshi yes that is it. It works now!  It is interesting that it worked so far as it did.  It looks like the & converts ds1 into a pure function and then, I cannot understand how it produced a dataset in the following  ds1[..] statement. Perhaps something to worry about another time.. How can I give you credit for this? thanks again.